# Getting the offending row and column when reading excel data using Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime, import

I've got a program that's reading an Excel worksheet using Pandas.  The program is able to import the worksheet fine if I remove two columns containing date data.

When the two columns are present and I attempt to read the workbook with

> ```
> webLinksPanda = pd.read_excel('/home/xyz/Documents/worksheet.ods', sheet_name='VidRecInv-LargeData', engine='odf')
> ```

I get this error

```
File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/np_datetime.pyx", line 212, in pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.check_dts_bounds
```

My question is, how can I find out the row and column that is causing the error?  I've got 6000 rows, so I'm not sure how I would find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can test whether reading the first *x* lines work:
`webLinksPanda = pd.read_excel('/home/xyz/Documents/worksheet.ods', sheet_name='VidRecInv-LargeData', engine='odf, nrows=x')`

Also, be aware that you may have further erroneous entries in those columns. So if you adjust one row which does not work and still get the error message afterwards, make sure to check further line numbers.

Comment: Good info.  The nrows comment allowed me to isolate one of my errors.  What I did notice is that line 212 does not refer to the error line in the Excel file.  It refers to a line in the pandas_lib file where the error occurred.  Really strange there isn't a better error message that indicates the line number.

Comment: You're right, my bad! I'll edit my answer accordingly.